# Tensorflow: Canonical method of diagnosing "No gradients provided for any variable..." errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a high level question about how to diagnose Tensorflow errors of the form:

> `No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables`

Of course I am interested in solving this for my specific problem, but that is not what this question is about. I would like a more canonical answer on the best way to find the place where the gradients "stop".

For instance, it would be nice to have a tool in Tensorboard that showed the parts of the graph which have gradients with respect to certain variables. In the specific example below, I could image the variable being blue, and then all of the lines and scopes that have gradients with respect to the Variable being colored blue. That sure would make it easy to trace such problems for large graphs...

Does such a feature exist? Or what is the canonical way of tracing such problems?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any tool helping with this error.

It is a typical error when you try to compute a gradient based on the output of some part of the graph w.r.t variables disconnected from the subgraph.

There is not doubt that this is a graph-architecture issue, there is a missing link between your gradient/loss and your trainable_var.

Comment: I understand that there is a disconnection causing this error, but I have an extremely large graph, and I already checked the easy, obvious things (like searching for cast operations). I also ran the network to make sure that the output indeed changes when I change the input. But somewhere the gradient is breaking down (which prevents me from optimizing the network). Tracking this down is the hard part

Comment: You have two solutions: 1. Try to implement unittests and dummy networks with one training for each "important" subpart of your graph, you will rapidly find your issue.
Example for a GAN: You test G, you test D; you test G-->D.
2. You try to replace large blocks with random operations which output the correct shape, and start training, if it trains and thus the problem is in the block you have bypassed.

Comment: That is what I am doing. But obviously this can take quite a bit of time since initializing everything in the network takes time. I have isolated where the issue is occurring for my particular case, which Is why I am asking for a canonical answer. I believe your previous comment would be an appropriate answer to my original question... If you think that that is indeed the "canonical way" of diagnosing such problems. After all, that is how I isolated my problem. I was just hoping that there would be a better way